# Display Dates that fall in a certain date range in a row

Tags: php, mysql, date, range

[image]

i want to display all the dates that fall in a certain date range 
like

```
select * from table where column names <'certain date'
```

i have tried select * from table where columns<'certain date'
but it doesn't work.
The Type of these columns is of date type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in MySQL if any date in a range of dates falls between dates held in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130602/how-to-check-in-mysql-if-any-date-in-a-range-of-dates-falls-between-dates-held-i)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `BETWEEN` operator to specify the date ranges like

```
where column_names between 'certain date' and 'certain other date'
```

(OR) using `>=` and `<=` operator

```
where column_names >= 'certain date' 
and column_names <= 'certain other date'
```

For multiple columns, you will have to include all of them using `and` / `or` condition

```
where column_name1 between 'certain date' and 'certain other date'
and   column_name2 between 'certain date' and 'certain other date'
```

Comment: It will but you will have to make them separately

Comment: this doesnt show any value if even one of the column returns false.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmed, then change the `and` condition to a `or` condition.

Comment: Well in that case post sample data along with desired output.